# Android Studio: Live Edit does not support running with this Kotlin Plugin version

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, liveedit

For some reason upon trying to use live edit (Manual mode / Ctrl + S) by changing the part of Composable and saving those changes, i get "paused" badge that signalize the following:

`Compilation Error: Live Edit does not support running with this Kotlin Plugin version and will only work with the bundled Kotlin Plugin.`

**Is there any workaround for this?** I have latest Kotlin Plugin version installed, alonside with kotlin 1.9.20 configured in `build.gradle` and respective `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` version for this (in my case 1.5.4)